# How do I update this code every second and minute with crontab

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi and a 16x2 LCD display with I2C to show the date, time (including seconds), and device's IP address.

The script is in the cron table and is scheduled to run every minute. Within the script itself, the seconds reload each second.

The code only works for exactly five minutes and then the text displayed starts to break. I'm not very experienced with Python so I appreciate any feedback to make this code more correct.

The cron table entry is just:

```
* * * * * python /home/pi/display.py
```

I mainly just manipulated the bottom of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import smbus
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

BUS = smbus.SMBus(1)

def write_word(addr, data):
    global BLEN
    temp = data
    if BLEN == 1:
            temp |= 0x08
    else:
            temp &= 0xF7
    BUS.write_byte(addr ,temp)

def send_command(comm):
    # Send bit7-4 firstly
    buf = comm & 0xF0
    buf |= 0x04               # RS = 0, RW = 0, EN = 1
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)
    time.sleep(0.002)
    buf &= 0xFB               # Make EN = 0
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)

    # Send bit3-0 secondly
    buf = (comm & 0x0F) << 4
    buf |= 0x04               # RS = 0, RW = 0, EN = 1
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)
    time.sleep(0.002)
    buf &= 0xFB               # Make EN = 0
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)

def send_data(data):
    # Send bit7-4 firstly
    buf = data & 0xF0
    buf |= 0x05               # RS = 1, RW = 0, EN = 1
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)
    time.sleep(0.002)
    buf &= 0xFB               # Make EN = 0
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)

    # Send bit3-0 secondly
    buf = (data & 0x0F) << 4
    buf |= 0x05               # RS = 1, RW = 0, EN = 1
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)
    time.sleep(0.002)
    buf &= 0xFB               # Make EN = 0
    write_word(LCD_ADDR ,buf)

def init(addr, bl):

    global LCD_ADDR
    global BLEN
    LCD_ADDR = addr
    BLEN = bl
    try:
            send_command(0x33) # Must initialize to 8-line mode at first
            time.sleep(0.005)
            send_command(0x32) # Then initialize to 4-line mode
            time.sleep(0.005)
            send_command(0x28) # 2 Lines & 5*7 dots
            time.sleep(0.005)
            send_command(0x0C) # Enable display without cursor
            time.sleep(0.005)
            send_command(0x01) # Clear Screen
            BUS.write_byte(LCD_ADDR, 0x08)
    except:
            return False
    else:
            return True

def clear():
    send_command(0x01) # Clear Screen

def openlight():  # Enable the backlight
    BUS.write_byte(0x27,0x08)
    BUS.close()

def write(x, y, str):
    if x < 0:
            x = 0
    if x > 15:
            x = 15
    if y <0:
            y = 0
    if y > 1:
            y = 1

    # Move cursor
    addr = 0x80 + 0x40 * y + x
    send_command(addr)

    for chr in str:
            send_data(ord(chr))


def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init(0x27, 1)
    write(0, 1, 'IP: ' + get_ip_address('wlan0'))
    write(0, 0, time.strftime('%b'))    #month
    write(4, 0, time.strftime('%d'))    #day of month
    write(8, 0, time.strftime('%H:'))   #hour
    write(11, 0, time.strftime('%M:'))  #minute

    while True:
        write(14, 0, time.strftime('%S'))#second
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, not a pastebin

Comment: And do you need cron, or is an infinite while loop in your code okay?

Comment: cron doesn't go subminute, so you need to do it differently.

Comment: There is an infinite loop inside his code...

Comment: Yeah, I would like this script to be run when the Pi boots up so that's why I put it in the crontable.

Answer (score 0):

please use this that is your solution

```
import time
import datetime
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD
from RPi import GPIO
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
lcd = CharLCD(numbering_mode=GPIO.BCM, pin_rs=22, pin_rw=24, pin_e=23, pins_data=[26, 12, 16, 27],cols=16, rows=2,auto_linebreaks=True)
lcd.cursor_pos = (0,1) 
lcd.write_string(u'WELCOME  SAJANARORA517')
while 1:    
    lcd.cursor_pos =(1,10)
    lcd.write_string("%s" %time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) 
    lcd.cursor_pos = (1,0)
    lcd.write_string("%s" %time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```